# Severe breaks and leaks

Tags: c, opencv

I have a code which basically detects playing cards, isolates them from a dynamic background based on HSV settings, then uses contours to detect the 4 points of the card to find the exact x and y position of the card. From there, the ROI is set and I can perform further processing to detect the face value of the card.

However, I the code seems to be breaking and I can't seem to find the root cause of it.
I have cleared images & memory storages, I've ensured that all the Iplimages have the same formatting and resolution.

```
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){ 
    IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(95,67,170), cvScalar(110,119,254), imgThresh); //Morning
    return imgThresh;
} 

IplImage* RedCheck(IplImage* imgBGR){ 
    IplImage* img=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgBGR),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvInRangeS(imgBGR, cvScalar(0,0,100), cvScalar(100,100,254), img); //BGR
    return img;
} 

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture =0;
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }

    IplImage* frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(48,64),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);

    while(true)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
        if(!frame) break;

        frame=cvCloneImage(frame); 
        cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the original image using Gaussian kernel
        IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
        cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); //Change the color format from BGR to HSV
        IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV);

        cvSmooth(imgThresh, imgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); //smooth the binary image using Gaussian kernel

        CvSeq* contours;
        CvSeq* result;
        CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        cvFindContours(imgThresh, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0)); 
        while(contours)
        {

            result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour),storage,CV_POLY_APPROX_DP,cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02,0);
            if(result->total == 4)
            {
                CvPoint *pt[4];
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {
                    pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result,i);
                }
                if (cvArcLength(result,CV_WHOLE_SEQ,1) >= 400)
                {
                    cvLine(imgThresh,*pt[0],*pt[1],cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                    cvLine(imgThresh,*pt[1],*pt[2],cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                    cvLine(imgThresh,*pt[2],*pt[3],cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
                    cvLine(imgThresh,*pt[3],*pt[0],cvScalar(255,0,0),4);



                    int ROIwidth = abs((*pt[0]).x - (*pt[1]).x);
                    int ROIheight = abs((*pt[1]).y - (*pt[2]).y);


                    cvSetImageROI(frame,cvRect((*pt[1]).x,(*pt[1]).y,ROIwidth,ROIheight));
                    IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
                    cvCopy(frame,temp,0);
                    cvResetImageROI(frame);
                    cvNamedWindow( "ROI", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                    cvShowImage( "ROI", temp);
                    printf("Width = %d\n",ROIwidth); //255-275
                    printf("Height = %d\n",ROIheight); //140-160
                    //Card Value Detection Starts Here


                    IplImage* colorcheck = RedCheck(temp);

                    int redpixelcheck = cvCountNonZero(colorcheck);
                    if (redpixelcheck <= 15)
                    {
                        printf("Card is Black\n");


                    }
                    else if (redpixelcheck >= 16)
                    {
                        printf("Card is Red\n");
                    }


                    //Card Value Detection Ends Here

                    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
                    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
                    cvReleaseImage(&colorcheck);


                    delete &ROIwidth;
                    delete &ROIheight;
                    delete &redpixelcheck;

                }
                //delete [] pt[4];
            }
            delete &result;
            contours = contours->h_next;
            //cvPutText (frame_t,text,cvPoint(200,400), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
        }

        cvNamedWindow( "Contour", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        cvShowImage( "Contour", imgThresh);
        cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Video", frame);

        //Clean up used images

        cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
        cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh); 
        cvReleaseImage(&frame);

        cvClearMemStorage(storage);
        cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);

        //Wait 50mS
        int c = cvWaitKey(10);
        //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
        if((char)c==27 ) break; 
    }
        cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        return 0;
    }
```

The disassembly always points to the same address
770915DE add esp,4

Comment: Writing an online Poker/Black Jack bot are you?  :)

Comment: delete &result; points to a C++ style library (and a really strange way of calling delete that may be an error).  Is this a C or a C++ app?

Comment: If you are writing a Poker/Black Jack bot, you are possibly using the wrong language as tool. Try ruby, python or anything else

Comment: you got me Michael.it is in C. I don't have much experience or knowledge on other languages.

Comment: `int ROIwidth` declares an ordinary `int` with automatic storage duration. `delete &ROIwidth;` won't compile as C, and in C++, it will cause breakage. `delete` only what you `new`ed.

Comment: it still breaks without the delete &integer lines. If I'm not mistaken, the error is something to do with the matrix array but I'm not too sure.. been cracking my head trying to find out the problem for a while now..

Comment: Does your disassembly have a callstack of any sort?  That would really help to localize the issue - which might be due to improper initialization of the cv stuff.  I'm not familiar with that at all, so I can't say for sure there.